# Hibernate uuid generator relational insertion

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid

Let's say I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<B> bs;

    // other fields + getter and setter
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class B {

    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID aId;

    // other fields + getter and setter
}
```

During a creation of entity `A` (save with JPA) which contains a list of `B`, Is there a way to use the `A's uuid generator` to populate `aId` field in `B` ? Or do I need to generate uuid using `UUID.randomUUID()` in java and then create `A/B` entities ?

Comment: Is each instance of `B` supposed to have its own UUID as primary key? Or is field `aId` supposed to be a reference to an instance of class `A`? Because in that case you can just make it `private A a` and specify the join column in B or  `mappedBy` in the @OneToMany relation.

Comment: `B primary key` is a composite key between `aId` and `code` another attribute of B. I tried what you have suggested but it did not work and I still get the error during a creation of `A` on the `B's aId` column. The null value in column "a_id" violates not-null constraint. The uuid generator works for `A` but is not used when `B` is created. How can I tell hibernate to set the composite key for `B` (`aId` + `code`) and set the `@ManyToOne` relation between `B` and `A` ?

Comment: So if I'm getting it right, each instance of `B` must refer to an `A` by its primary key (the generated UUID for A), and the primary key of B itself is a composite key with A's UUID and a field of B?

Comment: Yes. You're absolutely right.